# Symfony 4 invalid credentials on login

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, yaml, credentials

Learning Symfony is a tough journey and I knew posts on SO would follow, so here's my problem : classic login page, I followed [this tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) and before that I followed the [registration form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/registration_form.html) tutorial.

Registration works fine, user is inserted into the database with the correct informations, the problem is the login, because no matter what I've tried, the **Invalid Credentials** error message will pop-up, I tried with multiple users but nothing, I can't find the mistake, everything seems correct, I've checked many many times. So, time to show some code I guess :

My login form :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ path('login') }}">
...
...
<input type="text" name="_username" class="form-control" id="name"
                                   placeholder="Your username" value="{{ last_username }}" required autofocus>
...
...
<input type="password" name="_password" class="form-control" id="password"
                                   placeholder="Password" required>
                                   <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/admin" />
                                   <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
```

My Controller who handles the login :

```
     /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     * 
     */

    public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
    {

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('main/login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }
```

Basically a copy-paste from the tutorial. I've set the encored in my security.yalm file :

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        the_user_provider:
            entity: 
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: name

    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha512

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: ~

            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: true
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

            provider: the_user_provider

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Also, since I dont know what the problem could be, here's the portion of the registration logic that encodes the user password :

```
public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, Sluggify $sluggify) {
...
...
// 3) Encode the password (you could also do this via Doctrine listener)
            $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
            $user->setPassword($password);
```

And ofcourse inside my **User** entity I've already set a plainPassword and getPlainPassword:

```
     ...
     ...
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */

     private $password;

     /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
     */
    private $plainPassword;
   ...
   ...

   public function getPlainPassword()
       {
           return $this->plainPassword;
       }
```

For completition here are the last rows in my **dev.log** file :

```
[2018-03-17 16:35:06] request.INFO: Matched route "login". {"route":"login","route_parameters":{"_controller":"App\\Controller\\MainController::login","_route":"login"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/login","method":"POST"} []
[2018-03-17 16:35:06] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2, t0.email AS email_3, t0.slug AS slug_4, t0.avatar AS avatar_5, t0.password AS password_6, t0.is_author AS is_author_7, t0.is_active AS is_active_8 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.name = ? LIMIT 1 ["K3nzie"] []
[2018-03-17 16:35:06] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): Bad credentials. at /home/k3nzie/projects/symfonyWebsite/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php:88, Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): The presented password is invalid. at /home/k3nzie/projects/symfonyWebsite/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:65)"} []
[2018-03-17 16:35:06] security.DEBUG: Authentication failure, redirect triggered. {"failure_path":"login"} []
[2018-03-17 16:35:06] request.INFO: Matched route "login". {"route":"login","route_parameters":{"_controller":"App\\Controller\\MainController::login","_route":"login"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/login","method":"GET"} []
[2018-03-17 16:35:06] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2018-03-17 16:35:07] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"62995d","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/_wdt/62995d","method":"GET"} []
```

Any suggestions? I've looked the whole day for a solution, and I'm sure it's a silly beginner error, but still...nothing.

Comment: Start by verifying you have csrf enables in framework.yaml: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/csrf.html

Comment: Then, under security: add "hide_user_not_found:  false" Doing so will change the error message to either user not found or invalid password and narrow down the possible problem.  I suspect the problem is in your password encoding during registration.  Though what you have does look right.  Assuming your $user really is App\Entity\User and not the default Symfony user.

Comment: At the beginning I thought it was related to encoding too, that's why i followed the registration tutorial, so the process of encoding is made by symfony and should've worked fine (in my first try, I manually created the first user and inserted a sha512 password), anyway, I'm gonna try what you suggested :)

Answer (score 3):

Look problem in this pice of code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */

 private $password;
```

SHA512 actually returns a string of 128 length. So the short answer is, your field only needs to be 128 characters.

You should set length at 128 or more or not set at all and it will be set at 255 by default

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */

 private $password;
```

And after that changes you should fix field length in your database table manualy or through migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Try changing $user->getPlainPassword(). I believe that getPlainPassword is a form builder function and you have created your own form so you need to bind your variables with the request object.

In my code i did it like this.

```
$password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $params['password']);

/**
 * @Route("/register", name="user_registration")
 */
public function registerAction(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
{
    $params = $request->request->all();

    if ($request->isMethod("POST")) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setFname($params["fname"]);
        $user->setLname($params["lname"]);
        $user->setEmail($params["email"]);
        $user->setUsername($params["username"]);
        $user->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
        //$user->setPassword($params['password']);

        $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $params['password']);
        $user->setPassword($password);

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('login');

    }

    return $this->render(
        'default/register.html.twig'
    );
}
```